# Check if file name exists

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm using this powershell code to check if a file starting with 4 specific chars exist in a specific path or not

```
$myPath = "c:\myFolder\";
$myFileBegin = "abc_";
test-path "$myPath$myFileBegin*";
```

It works and it's simple, but now
I'm trying to do the same thing with C#.
I don't report all the code but basically I'm getting all files from the folder with `Directory.GetFiles` and looping over those files and testing with `Regex.IsMatch`. 
Is this the correct way or is there a faster one like in powershell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a search filter in the call to `Directory.GetFiles()`:

```
Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\myFolder\", "abc_*.*");
```

This will return only files that start with `abc_`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\myFolder\").Where(x => x.StartsWith("abc_"));
```

Answer (score 1):

with .net 4 and above:

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"c:\myFolder", "abc_*.*")).Any()  ? true : false
```

this return `(bool)` true or false belong the case